# glBufferData with an array of verticies that have 3 floats (x, y and z) each

Tags: c++, opengl

Currently I am trying to draw a triangle via a mesh class. I do this by first initializing the glew and the calling the Window.initializeGraphics method of my Window class, then creatubg an array of verticies and passing to my Mesh.addVerticies method. Each vertex has 3 floats, x, y, and z. Then I call the Mesh.draw method every tick of the main game loop.

initializeGraphics Method:

```
void Window::initializeGraphics()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);
}
```

Creating the Mesh:

```
    m_Mesh = Mesh();

    Vertex data[] = { Vertex(vec3(-1, -1, 0)),
                      Vertex(vec3(1, -1, 0)),
                      Vertex(vec3(0,  1, 0)) };

    m_Mesh.addVerticies(data);
```

Mesh Header:

```
#include "vertex.h"
#include <GLEW\glew>
class Mesh
{
private:
    GLuint m_Vbo;
    int m_Size;
public:
    Mesh();
    void addVerticies(Vertex verticies[]);
    void draw();
};
```

Mesh C++ File:

```
#include "mesh.h"
Mesh::Mesh()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_Vbo);
}

void Mesh::addVerticies(Vertex verticies[])
{
    m_Size = (sizeof(verticies) / sizeof(*verticies));

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticies), verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Mesh::draw()
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * 4, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_Size);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Vertex Header:

```
#include "vec3.h"
struct Vertex
{   
    union
    {
        vec3 pos;
        struct 
        {
            float x, y, z;
        };
    };
    Vertex(vec3 pos_);
};
```

Vertex C++ File:

```
#Include "vertex.h"
Vertex::Vertex(vec3 pos_)
{
    pos = pos_;
}
```

Render Method:

```
void MainComponent::render()
{
    m_Window.clear();

    m_Mesh.draw();

    m_Window.update();
}
//m_Window.update();
void Window::update() 
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(m_GLFWWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
//m_Window.clear();
void Window::clear()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

Problem is, no triangle appears on screen. What am I doing wrong ? I am pretty much still a C++ newling, and this is my first time programming OpenGl so it could be something really really basic that I keep overlooking.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

-Sean

Comment: glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticies), verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW). Check the value of sizeof(vertices) to see if it's correct. Also, where is the shader code?

Comment: @PedroDavid it isn't thx need to fix that too thanks. but i found the reason why it didn't render.

Answer (score 1):

Woah, hold on there!  There are other bona fide errors here.

```
void Mesh::addVerticies(Vertex verticies[])
{
    // This gives the wrong answer!
    m_Size = (sizeof(verticies) / sizeof(*verticies));
```

That calculation for `m_Size` is completely wrong. This is because `verticies` is a *pointer* not an array.  It looks like an array, it was declared as `Vertex verticies[]`, but due to a quirk of C++ (the same applies to C) the parameter decays into a pointer.  So it ends up being the same as this:

```
void Mesh::addVerticies(Vertex *verticies)
```

As you can see, `sizeof(verticies)` is always going to be 8 on a typical 64-bit system, because you are just getting the size of a pointer, not the size of an array.

We can fix this by capturing the size of the array with a template:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void addVertices(Vertex (&vertices)[N]) {
    addVertices(vertices, N);
}

void addVertices(Vertex *vertices, std::size_t count) {
    m_Size = count;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Vbo);
    glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
        sizeof(*vertices) * count,
        vertices,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Because we use a reference to the array, `Vertex (&vertices)[N]`, instead of the array directly, `Vertex vertices[N]`, the parameter does not decay into a pointer.

Comment: Thanks i noticed soon after i posted the question. i now use `m_Size = sizeof(*verticies) / sizeof(verticies);` wich also seems to work out.

Comment: @SeanO'Hanlon: That is incorrect.  `sizeof(*verticies) / sizeof(verticies)` does not give the correct answer because `verticies` is a pointer, so you you will always get the same result, no matter how large the array is.

Comment: i am kinda confused how i should implement this. Would you mind explaining it ?

Comment: Basically, `sizeof(*x)` doesn't give you the answer you want if `x` is an array that you pass to a function.  So you need to pass the size of the array as a function parameter, or use another trick (like the template) to do it for you.  C++ is full of little flaws like this which make the language more difficult to use without any real benefit.

Comment: and how would i implement the `template <std::size_t N>
void addVertices(Vertex (&vertices)[N]) {
    addVertices(vertices, N);
}` part ?

Comment: @SeanO'Hanlon: I'm a little confused, because that is a complete function.  I have included the entire source code there for you.

Comment: nvm, i got it. sorry for confusing you :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a complete moron... One verticie was off the screen. I think I'll call it a day :/

Comment: That's not how clipping is supposed to work, by the way. If one vertex in a polygon is "offscreen" (outside the viewing volume), the remaining portion is still filled.

Comment: not when the remaining two are in the bottom cornoers and the missing one is below them